# How can I make the below code shorter or refactor it while providing all the upper siblings a certain rewards?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

How can I make the below code shorter or refactor it while providing all the upper siblings a certain rewards? well am making a reward giving system for the user and I have no idea how to shorter this below code?

```
public static function reward_members()
    {
        $loop = 5;
        // foreach (range(1, $loop) as $item) {
        $member_code = SalesMember::select('user_id', 'member_code')->where('referral_code', request('member_code'))->first();
        if (!empty($member_code)) {
            self::reward_points($point = 5, auth('api')->id() ?? auth()->id());
            $member_code_first = SalesMember::select('user_id', 'member_code')->where('referral_code', $member_code)->first();

            if (!empty($$member_code_first)) {
                self::reward_points($point = 4, $member_code_first->user_id);
                $member_code_second = SalesMember::select('user_id', 'member_code')->where('referral_code', $member_code_first)->first();

                if (!empty($member_code_second)) {
                    self::reward_points($point = 3, $member_code_second->user_id);
                    $member_code_third = SalesMember::select('user_id', 'member_code')->where('referral_code', $member_code_second)->first();

                    if (!empty($member_code_third)) {
                        self::reward_points($point = 2, $member_code_third->user_id);
                        $member_code_fourth = SalesMember::select('user_id', 'member_code')->where('referral_code', $member_code_third)->first();

                        if (!empty($member_code_fourth)) {
                            self::reward_points($point = 1, $member_code_fourth->user_id);
                            $member_code_fifth = SalesMember::select('user_id', 'member_code')->where('referral_code', $member_code_fourth)->first();

                            if (!empty($member_code_fifth)) {
                                self::reward_points($point = 1, $member_code_fifth->user_id);
                                $member_code_third = SalesMember::select('user_id', 'member_code')->where('referral_code', $member_code_fifth)->first();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            self::reward_points($point = 5, auth('api')->id() ?? auth()->id());
        }
        // }
    }
```

here is the reward_points()

```
public static function reward_points($point, $user_id)
    {
        $reward  = RewardManage::latest()->select('balance')->where('user_id', $user_id)->first();

        $balance = $reward->balance ?  $reward->balance : 0;

        $sales_by  = ProductCode::select('buyer_id', 'product_code_value')->where('product_code', request('product_code'))->first();
        $reward_point = $point * $sales_by->product_code_value;
        $rewardInsert = [
            'user_id' => auth()->id() ?? auth('api')->id(),
            'sales_by' => $sales_by->buyer_id,
            'product_code' => request('product_code'),
            'reward_points' => $reward_point,
            'balance' => $balance + $reward_point,
        ];
        RewardManage::create($rewardInsert);
    }
```

Comment: What does `self::reward_points()` do?

Comment: well, I have added the second function now please have a look at it.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you use `reward_points($point = 1, ..` instead of `reward_points(1, ...` for the first argument of `reward_points`?

Comment: well, it's just a random value for now but in the future, it will mange from the database for dynamic values

Answer (score 1):

The following can be used instead of the nested for loops:

```php
public static function reward_members()
{
    // Find member who's referral_code is used
    $memberWithUsedReferral = SalesMember::select('user_id', 'member_code')->where('referral_code', request('member_code'))->first();

    // If no sales-member has this referral code, award the currently authenticated user
    if (empty($memberWithUsedReferral)) {
        self::reward_points(5, auth('api')->id() ?? auth()->id());
        return;
    }

    $pointsToAward = 5;

    while($memberWithUsedReferral != null){
        // Give the member sales-member that has the referral_code points
        self::reward_points($pointsToAward, $memberWithUsedReferral->user_id);

        // Find the if there is a sales-manager that has the referral_code if the current sales-manager
        $memberWithUsedReferral = SalesMember::select('user_id', 'member_code')->where('referral_code', $memberWithUsedReferral->member_code)->first();

        // Decrease points by one with a one point minimum
        $pointsToAward = $pointsToAward === 1
            ? $pointsToAward
            : $pointsToAward - 1;
    }
}
```